# Mysql5.6 select statement with duplicate id and set

Tags: mysql, select, set

I have a table A containing id (auto incremented) as a primary key and a table B containing id as a foreign key.While selecting data from Table B if there are duplicate ids then append a number with empid.

```
TableA
id  empid   name    place
1   ab123   John    SL
2   gh345   Lucy    AK
3   hj890   Mike    KL
```

```
TableB
id class
1 A
1 B
1 A
2 A
3 A
```

```
Output
ab123,SL,A
ab123,SL,B
ab123,SL,A
gh345,AK,A
hj890,KL,A
```

Desired output

```
ab123-1,SL,A
ab123-2,SL,B
ab123-3,SL,A
gh345,AK,A
hj890,KL,A
```

This is what I have tried

```
SELECT TableA.empid, ",", TableA.place, ",", TableB.class 
FROM TableA 
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.id = TableB.id
```

Comment: And what result do you get from what you have tried

Comment: @RiggsFolly: added my current output to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With mysql 8 You can do following code, in mysql 6.x you need to use user-defined variables instead of the window finction

> ```
> CREATE TABLE TableA (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `empid` VARCHAR(5),
>   `name` VARCHAR(4),
>   `place` VARCHAR(2)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO TableA
>   (`id`, `empid`, `name`, `place`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'ab123', 'John', 'SL'),
>   ('2', 'gh345', 'Lucy', 'AK'),
>   ('3', 'hj890', 'Mike', 'K');
>
> CREATE TABLE TableB (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `class` VARCHAR(1)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO TableB
>   (`id`, `class`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'A'),
>   ('1', 'B'),
>   ('1', 'A'),
>   ('2', 'A'),
>   ('3', 'A');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT CONCAT(`empid`,IF(co > 1,CONCAT('-',`rn`),''),',',`place`,',',`class`) AS 'empid,place,class'
> FROM
> (SELECT
> empid,place,class, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empid ) rn
> , countB.co
> FROM TableA 
> INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.id = TableB.id
> INNER JOIN (SELECT id,COUNT(*) co FROM TableB GROUP BY id) countB  ON TableB.id = countB.id) t1
> ```
>
> ```
> | empid,place,class |
> | :---------------- |
> | ab123-1,SL,A      |
> | ab123-2,SL,B      |
> | ab123-3,SL,A      |
> | gh345,AK,A        |
> | hj890,K,A         |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=850fcc188f65ae614679712b759a632e)*

MySQL 5.x Version

> ```
> SELECT CONCAT(`empid`,IF(co > 1,CONCAT('-',`rn`),''),',',`place`,',',`class`) AS 'empid,place,class'
> FROM
> (SELECT
> place,class, IF(@id = empid,@rn := @rn+1, @rn := 1) rn
> ,@id := empid as empid
> ,countB.co
> FROM TableA 
> INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.id = TableB.id
> INNER JOIN (SELECT id,COUNT(*) co FROM TableB GROUP BY id) countB  ON TableB.id = countB.id
> CROSS JOIN (SELECT @id :=0,@rn:=0) t2
> ORDER BY empid) t1
> ```
>
> ```
> | empid,place,class |
> | :---------------- |
> | ab123-1,SL,A      |
> | ab123-2,SL,B      |
> | ab123-3,SL,A      |
> | gh345,AK,A        |
> | hj890,K,A         |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=3c82aef2a466522a36d45723a1f063e6)*

Comment: Thanks @nbk. But this code wont work with mysql 5.6.

Comment: 5.6 is very old. Please add the version, if you have questions especiylly when dealing with rdms. i adde3d a mysql 5.x version

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly.